# Basic question about expectation

Tags: probability, measure-theory, self-learning, expected-value, solution-verification

Let $(A,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space, $f$ real, bounded, nonnegative, measurable function and $X,Y$ real random variables so that $E(Y)=0$.

Then $E(f(X)Y)=0$.

**My arguments**

$$0=-C\int YdP\leq\int -f(X)YdP\leq\int f(X)YdP\leq C\int YdP=0,$$
for some constant $C>0$.

*I just realize that the second inequlity does not need to hold.

Can you give me feedbacks about it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about $X=0$ if $Y<0$ and $X=1$ if $Y>0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and some non-zero variable $Y$

Comment: I think the above result does not hold in general. It is needed stronger assumptions like independence of $X,Y$ or $E(Y \mid X)=0$.

Comment: Counterexample for the result as stated: let $f(x) = 1$, let $X$ have a standard normal distribution, and let $Y = X$; then $\mathbb E[f(X)Y] = 1$. Some other condition is apparently needed here.